# Correct way to send push notifications

Tags: android, notifications, google-play, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send a notification from some server to android device. The most obvious(and power-hungry) way is to keep searching some database for any new messages using a service/broadcast receiver.

I am sure there are other ways to get this job done. I took a look at GCM(google cloud messaging) , and it seems that google always keeps some TCP/IP connection active. This essentially means that using GCM will use less power.

However, I have a few questions regarding GCM.

1. Does a user NEED to have google services, and a registered play id ?
2. If a user side-loads an apk, will he still be able to receive notifications ?

I would like to know if there are alternatives to GCM

What about devices running forked android versions, like nokia X , kindle etc? How are push notifications sent to those devices ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html q1: yes, `It requires devices running Android 2.2 or higher that also have the Google Play Store application installed` q2: yes, `However, you are not limited to deploying your Android applications through Google Play Store` for nokia and kindle - do those devices have google play store?

Comment: i have read that. i want to ask if its possible to get push notifications without GCM , without checking constantly

Comment: so i have to vote for close, as `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`

Answer (score 1):

> Does a user NEED to have google services, and a registered play id ?

Yes, it is necessary to use Google Play Services in your development. However users do not need to have a Google account or the Google Play Services Installed.

> If a user side-loads an apk, will he still be able to receive notifications ?

Yes.

The steps that must be followed to send a notification to a device are:

1. Developer creates application in [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com)
2. User installs application
3. Application gets a NotificationID and sends it to your database
4. You store the NotificationID at your servers with any other information related (your username, device info, etc.)
5. Whenever you want to send a Notification you connect to GCM sending one or more NotificationID and the notification content.
6. The users related to the NotificationID will receive in your Application the notification content.
7. Do any action you need.

Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html).

IMHO there is not any real alternative to GCM in Android (based on efficiency and simplicity). You may look for 3rd party services that will help you in the implementation and add value (marketing, business intelligence). As an example of this take a look to [UrbanShip](http://urbanairship.com/).

If you want to implement your own solution you should have a look to [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). This will mantain an active communication between your server and the device. Those sockets are thought for real time communication between your server and the mobile.

Two issues:

- How is the application affecting the battery depends on your implementation and the application use-case (how frecuent are you sending information, how long is the connection stablished).
- I am not aware of any native implementation of this in Android but there are a few Libraries coming from open source projects. Google it.

Comment: suppose i make my own notification service, how do I talk to my server without impacting the battery life much ?

Comment: In my opinion, any solution you implement will impact in users battery or will not be as inmediate as GCM. You can have a look to WebSockets (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) as the very best alternative.